# Cisco Prime / 5508 WLC captive portals

Tags: wireless, wlc, cisco-wireless, byod

Need some assistance with a small query.
Can a 5508 WLC be configured to host multiple concurrent captive portals?
Have been googling for the information but if anyone has the info available, I would appreciate it.
Thanks:-)

Comment: Thanks Ricky Beam and Generalnetworkerror. I would consider this query solved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this [Configuration Guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/wireless-mobility/wlan-security/71881-ext-web-auth-wlc.html#c5), it would appear to only support one portal. I don't know if there's a way to specify the SSID (network) to the portal page / WLC. (I've never needed to. [it's in the `wlan` query param])

Update: Apparently 7.3+ can, but it's a lot more involved. "[Assigning Login, Login Failure, and Logout Pages per WLAN](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/7-3/configuration/guide/b_cg73/b_wlc-cg_chapter_01011.html#d104691e2151a1635)"

Answer (score 4):

Not directly on the WLC, but using **Cisco ACS**, ISE or other RADIUS server, you can set the captive URL using the `url-redirect` value of the `cisco-av-pair` RADIUS attribute.  This **overrides** the WLC default setting for **External Webauth URL**.  You can also set the url-redirect-acl to match a named ACL on the WLC.

[image: ACS url-redirect RADIUS attribute]

Comment: Nice to know, but not useful here as there won't be a login event until they've already been directed to the portal. For a dot1x authenticated client, sure, but why would you send an already authenticated client to a captive portal?

Comment: @RickyBeam, one possible reason to redirect a dot1x client is forcing internal users to agree to an AUP / EULA every time.  If they have already authenticated, you can associate an identity with that AUP / EULA agreement.